# Donation options in an app - Are any of these allowed?

Tags: iphone, app-store, appstore-approval

Are any of these options allowed regarding accepting donations through an iPhone app, without "losing" 30% of the money to Apple?

- A button which links to a web page that accepts donations with credit card payments?
- Instructions on how to donate by sending an SMS message?
- Call a IVR service where you can bill the people donating on their phone bill?

Comment: From what i could google, all your 3 options seems valid. Try reading this http://www.iphonedownloadblog.com/2010/12/24/apple-is-denying-in-app-donations-to-developers/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## 2014 - please note all answers here are years out of date.

## 2014 - hopefully someone will post updated facts.

---

I'm pretty sure you are **not** allowed to do this currently - although these policies change frequently.

If you're interested in spam, donations (however well meaning), or viruses, that "android" system which google launched to allow that sort of thing, is exactly what you're looking for.

## Sorry, I was wrong, you ARE currently allowed to do this:

> 21. Charities and contributions
>
> > 21.1 Apps that include the ability to make donations to recognized charitable organizations must be free
> > 21.2 The collection of donations must be done via a web site in Safari or an SMS

That's the answer, April 2011.  You must use one of the two methods in 21.2.

For the convenience of future readers: Trydis, who asked the original question, has helpfully supplied this great URL link: https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/

Comment: Thanks, here's the link for anyone interested: https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html

Comment: Ehm... you're not answering the question. The piece you are quoting is about donations to RECOGNIZED CHARITABLE ORGANIZATIONS. As the original poster did not mention anything about those, you shouldn't assume that's what he's talking about.

Answer (score 0):

From what I know, Apple doesn't allow you to include a donation button in your application. 
AppMakr quoted: 
“Apple tends to reject Apps that have content related to donations or charity. We have issued you a coupon “REMOVED” which will enable you to rebuild your App for free, minus the tab related to donations.”